# Buttons inside ion-item is always triggered

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms

I have an ion-item with an ion-input and a right aligned `ion-button`. Whenever I click the input field, the button is triggered. How can I separate the input field from the button?

```
<ion-item slot="end">
    <ion-input [formControl]="formattedFormControl" (ionChange)="inputChange($event)"></ion-input>
    <ion-button fill="clear" [id]="id" >
        <ion-icon icon="calendar"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
    <ion-popover [trigger]="id"
                 show-backdrop="true">
        <ng-template>
            <ion-datetime #datetime
                          [locale]="languageCode"
                          presentation="date"
                          (ionChange)="datetimeChange($event)">
            </ion-datetime>
        </ng-template>
    </ion-popover>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was using the id with an `Input()` directive. Therefore the `id` was added to the components tag and was triggering the `ion-popover`.
The solution, in this case, was to add a prefix to the id:

```
[id]="idPrefix + id"

[trigger]="idPrefix + id"
```